# How to use Grove Connectors with the ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB development board?

Tags: esp32, grove-connector

I am plug & play, non-soldering type.

As such, I love [Grove Connectors](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_System/).

Does anyone know of a non-soldering, preferably non-breadboard,  way to use them with the [ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB development board](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32945629720.html)?

[Update] I never did figure out how to do this, and the only answerer hasn't logged in for a long time. Does anyone know how? I like the ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB because it had an on board debugger (and display).

Answer (score 3):

I have some doubt I fully understand the question (as the answer seems too simple) but I'll try nonetheless.

Two options that came to mind right away:

- Get a plain [Grove I2C Hub](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-I2C_Hub/) with 4 ports or more, split a Grove cable on one end and attach individual jumper wires (similar to what I do [here](https://frightanic.com/uncategorized/cheap-grove-0-96-oled-display-module/)), plug those into the dev board.
- Get a [Grove Base Shield](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_Base_Shield_for_NodeMCU_V1.0/) for e.g. NodeMCU, use male-to-female jumper wires to connect the MCU connectors on the shield with the dev board.

**Update**

Here's a quickly stitched together photo more clearly describing (I hope) the 2nd idea. You can use any Grove Base Shield; nothing to do with NodeMCU. You will be feeding Vin/GND and the 2 I2C lines into the connectors of shield from the dev board. The Grove connectors will never know whether they are feeding or being fed by NodeMCU or the dev board.

[image]

Comment: You understood correctly (upvote), although I not sure if you fully grokked "`I am plug & play, non-soldering type`" :-)  For instance "similar to what I do [here](https://frightanic.com/uncategorized/cheap-grove-0-96-oled-display-module/)" contains the words "`Solder a jumper wire onto each strand of the Grove cable`" and NodeMCU seems to be eSP286 based firmware. There are a few ESP32s which have Arduino pin-out, so I can use one pf those and a an Arduino Grove shield, but I would really prefer some kind of plug & play solution for the  ESP-WROVER-KIT-VB development board

Comment: That's why I said *similar* - I'm sure there are creative ways to achieve the same without soldering. "NodeMCU" is both a dev kit and a firmware that allows you to program the ESP8266/32 using the Lua language (I'm a committer with that project). That's not the point, though. You won't be using NodeMCU at all. Allow me to update the answer and make that more clear.

Comment: Thanks! Look like I don't need to solder right? What about the wiring? Which pin goes to which?